# Some contacts are shown as LAST, FIRST; some as FIRST, LAST

Tags: contacts

On **Constituent Summary page** in **Contact name** column I see contacts listed in two different formats.

1) Last, Name

2) Name Last

Also, in search boxes, CiviCRM provides suggestions in these two formats.

How can I get all contacts displayed the same way (e.g. First Last)?

Comment: Related question: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/872/is-there-a-way-to-regenerate-the-display-and-sort-names

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your greetings/display name format has changed at some point in time.

You can run the "Update Greetings" job to force a refresh, I would create a copy of the job and set the relevant force flags so that its not constantly refreshing.

You can get to the Schduled Jobs page from the Admin -> System settings menu.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the hint. 

I manually executed all 3 scripts separately for email_greeting, postal_greeting and addressee with Success. However, in Search box (top left) and in Constituent Report the contacts are still in mixed formats.

Is it possible (as I see in Constituent Report Developer tab) these values are **contact_civireport.sort_name** as **civicrm_contact_sort_name**.

Is there something I can do with those?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this solution and it worked:
[Is there a way to regenerate the display and sort names?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/872/is-there-a-way-to-regenerate-the-display-and-sort-names)

Basically it requires exporting and re-importing Contact Names and Contact ID. The display and sort names are regenerated automatically.